# findByIdAndUpdate doesnt update anything

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

im following a tutorial but it seems to be old and it looks like things have been changed , I have a edit page which is trying to edit existing data in mongodb but it just doesnt want to work.

here is what the guy in the tutorial did:

```
app.put("/blogs/:id",function(req,res){
Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,req.body.blog,function(err,updatedBlog){
if (err) {
  res.redirect("/blogs");
}else {
  res.redirect("/blogs/" + req.params.id);
}
  });
});
```

since then i tried with findOneAndUpdate() but i cant seem to work that one out as well i tried replacing .id with ._id like this:

```
app.put("/blogs/:id",function(req,res){
   Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id,req.body,{new:true},function(err,updatedBlog){
if(err){
  console.log(err);
}else{
  console.log("Blog updated");
  res.redirect("/blogs/"+req.params._id);
}
  });
});
```

and it's going to the else statement because i get the console.log but it still doesn't update anything

Comment: instead of `{new:true}` can you try {upsert:true} ? and can you also post what req.body contains?

Comment: i added console.log(req.body); to the else , and it seems to be getting the information i edit in the input of the page the console log returns { blog:
   { title: 'Test Blog1111',
     image:
      'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7250/7775397718_c676fbeb4b.jpg',
     body: 'Hello this is a blog post!' } } which is what i edited but after i go and refresh the page its back to normal

Comment: after i changed new to upsert everytime i go to the index page i get "
Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined"

Comment: can you post the code where you are actually accessing the data, where you are using substring keyword there

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty <% include partials/header %>

<h1>Index page</h1>

<% for(var i=0;i<blogs.length;i++){ %>
  <h1><%= blogs[i].title %></h1>
  <img src="<%=blogs[i].image %>" alt="image of a blog">
  <span><%= blogs[i].created.toDateString() %></span>
  <p><%= blogs[i].body.substring(0,100) %> ...</p>
  <a href="/blogs/<%= blogs[i]._id %>">Read More</a>
<% } %>

<% include partials/footer %>

Comment: so in your case ` blogs[i].body` is not coming as expected, try to print or debug it somewhere, and check whats the value of `blogs[i]` and ` blogs[i].body` is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your update query is not in proper format.

Your query should be like [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

```
    Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: {blog: req.body.blog}}, function(err, updatedData){
        if(err){console.log(err);}
        else{ console.log('blog  updated');
         // do other stuff.....
        }

})
```

Comment: i can't even test this because i changed {new:true} to {upsert:true} and every time i go to the index page i instantly get an error `
    7|   <img src="<%=blogs[i].image %>" alt="image of a blog">
    8|   <span><%= blogs[i].created.toDateString() %></span>
 >> 9|   <p><%= blogs[i].body.substring(0,100) %> ...</p>
    10|   <a href="/blogs/<%= blogs[i]._id %>">Read More</a>
    11| <% } %>
    12|

Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined `

Comment: Your array of object contain null or blank value i.e blogs[i].body So first you should print without  using substring() method Or use this code
<%= (blogs[i].body != null)? blogs[i].body.substring(0,100):'';%>

Comment: so i removed the substring part and now it renders the index page of course its rendering the entire blog.body but i still get the error `    { CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5c367bd3c1cbd03708d560f1 " at path "_id" for model "Blog" `

Answer (score 0):

at the end of the parameter req.body you forgot to add the blog so it should be

```js
Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,req.body.blog,function(error, updatedBlog)
```